# gerrit change-merged hook not executing

Tags: gerrit

I am trying to use `change-merged` hook in Gerrit. Below is my `gerrit.config`:

```
[hooks]
    path = /home/gerrit2/gerrit_testsite/hooks/
    changeMergedHook = change-merged
    commentAddedHook = comment-added
```

and I have done an echo to print a line in `change-merged` hook kept at `gerrit_site/hooks/` directory. Am I  missing some configuration?

Comment: `gerrit_testsite` and `gerrit_site` are not the same. Is that the problem? Is the script executable? Does the gerrit log say anything about this?

Comment: Did you execute an "echo <something>" inside the script? Where did you expect to see the message printed?